# How to stop a function after ten seconds?

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I found this piece of code while trying to find out a way to load a reddit page so that I can use ctrl + f to find a specific post. The problem is that it just keeps scrolling down and loading the pages. I need to find a way to stop  it after 10 seconds so that I can take a look at what I loaded. Also I don't know any javascript so I couldn't really find anythig that would help me.

Here is the code

```
var lastScrollHeight = 0;
function autoScroll() {
  var sh = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  if (sh != lastScrollHeight) {
    lastScrollHeight = sh;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = sh;
  }
}
window.setInterval(autoScroll, 100);
```

I just paste that into the firefox console.

Comment: use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: Welcome! Really well-formed first question! +1 / Tip: You can include runnable JavaScript/CSS/HTML code using the code snippet button instead of the simple code block format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will simply need to call [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) on your looped function to stop it after using a `setTimeout` set to 10 seconds, here is how you can implement it :

```
var lastScrollHeight = 0;
function autoScroll() {
    var sh = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    if (sh != lastScrollHeight) {
        lastScrollHeight = sh;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = sh;
    }
}
const interval = window.setInterval(autoScroll, 100);
window.setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(interval)}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks, the code worked just like I wanted to but just found out that just scrolling down doesn't actually load the posts so I cant really use ctrl + f to find what I wanted to. lol

Comment: @leo Are you authoring a userscript in GreaseMonkey/TemperMonkey? If possible it would be the better approach to invoke the AJAX-function of the page directly each time when new content has been loaded. Which site are you tweaking?

Answer (score 2):

To stop the interval after a certain amount of time use a `setTimeout()` that calls `clearInterval()`. Here's a simplified version (with the time reduced to 1 second for demo purposes) that should help:

```js
function autoScroll(){
  console.log("running")
}

// save a reference to the interval handle
let interval = window.setInterval(autoScroll, 100);

// cancel interval after 1 second (1000 ms)
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 1000)
```

Comment: Not 10 seconds but 1 (should at least be mentioned), however, this is my favored answer since it uses local scope keyword `let` and is formatted as runnable snippet.

Comment: That's a fair point @Quasimodo'sclone, I added a comment about the one second — just didn't want to have to wait 10 seconds to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval()` function returns an ID, which you can use to stop it.
Just put it in `setTimeout()` method like this:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(autoscroll, 100);
setTimeout(function(){ clearInterval(myInterval); }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
....
var intervalID = window.setInterval(autoScroll, 100);

setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to call the function until 10s are up.

Here's an immediately-invoked function that calls itself every 100th sec until 10s has been reached.

```js
(function autoScroll(t) {
  t = t || 0;
  if (t < 10000) {
    console.log(t);
    setTimeout(autoScroll, 100, t += 100);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Nice approach of self invoking function expression. Should run at an interval of 100 millisec. Improvement: Count down to 0 and invoke with the desired duration time.